# Edit shipping methods in Onepage Checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout, magento-1.6

I'm editing my checkout and would like to modify the display of shipping methods. I came across call block `$this->getChildHtml('available')`, but did not find the file corresponding phtml.

I'm also saving a session variable in the cart. This variable is available throughout the purchase process? At what point the session variables are related to cart "cleaned"?

Obs: CE 1.6.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available shipping methods block is declared in the [checkout.xml](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.6.1.0/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml#L327) layout file - the template used is `checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`.

Upon successful checkout (or if the session were to time out), the session is cleared in [Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::successAction()](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.6.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php#L227).

Comment: I found it. My theme don't has this file and I created it. Thanks you.